# copy file now paste later

Tags: linux, copy-paste

in linux to copy and paste a file we have cp command

```
cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

But what if I don't want to paste the file to any directory right now and I just want to copy it for future use? For example in GUI

```
right click to file>click on copy 
#Do something else change directory/use internet/have coffee
Right click at some other directory/place>click on 'Paste' >file will be pasted at DIRECTORY
```

same procedure is applied to cut/move the file. Is there any command for such copy/cut in linux??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the name of the file to a variable.

```
$ file_to_copy=`pwd`/important_notes.txt
```

`cd` elsewhere, use internet, have coffee. Ok, we want that file in our current directory.

```
$ cp $file_to_copy .
```

Use `mv` to move instead of copy.

(Please don't call this copy-pasting. It's just copying. Note that the initial `$` represents the prompt, don't type that.)

Answer (score 1):

The method above only copies the *name* of the file, not the file itself, which is fine, unless it gets modified or deleted in the meantime.

You might be better off copying the file to `/tmp/`

```
cp theFileIWant.txt /tmp/
cd wherever
mv /tmp/theFileIWant.txt ./
```